# Change excel's default cursor

Tags: excel, excel-365

For years and years, my default excel cursor was always the arrow pointer/clicker. All of a sudden it seems to be a big fat gross plus sign and I hate every second I have to look at it. I know there is a VB macro I can write that will call the default cursor, but that having to do that every single time I make or load an excel file is going to slow me down and drive me insane. Does anyone know how I can permanently set the default back to my sleek and lovely arrow?

Answer (score 0):

Drag and drop needs to be enabled.

To enable drag and drop, select File > Options
Under Options, select Advanced
Under Editing Options, select "Enable fill handle and cell drag and drop"
Click OK

Comment: Thank you, this is one of the first things I tried and it had no effect, it was already enabled as well.